# Converting Spark dataframe to Dask dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dask, dask-dataframe

First, I'm writing Spark df named calendar as a parquet file named cal.

calendar.write.parquet("/user/vusal.babashov/dataset/cal", mode="overwrite")

Then, I'm copying it from Hadoop to my personal folder.

!hdfs dfs -copyToLocal -f /user/vusal.babashov/dataset/cal /home/vusal.babashov/dataset

Finally, I'm trying to read the parquet into Dask.

import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_parquet('/home/vusal.babashov/dataset/cal')

This last step is where I keep getting OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument error. The path is correct and the parquet file named cal is there (I can confirm).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-372cb3d97d10> in <module>
      1 import dask.dataframe as dd
----> 2 df = dd.read_parquet('/home/vusal.babashov/dataset/cal')
      3 df

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py in read_parquet(path, columns, filters, categories, index, storage_options, engine, gather_statistics, split_row_groups, read_from_paths, chunksize, aggregate_files, **kwargs)
    325         chunksize=chunksize,
    326         aggregate_files=aggregate_files,
--> 327         **kwargs,
    328     )
    329 

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/fastparquet.py in read_metadata(cls, fs, paths, categories, index, gather_statistics, filters, split_row_groups, chunksize, aggregate_files, **kwargs)
    732         # correspond to a row group (populated below).
    733         parts, pf, gather_statistics, base_path = _determine_pf_parts(
--> 734             fs, paths, gather_statistics, **kwargs
    735         )
    736 

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/fastparquet.py in _determine_pf_parts(fs, paths, gather_statistics, **kwargs)
    163         elif gather_statistics is not False:
    164             # Scan every file
--> 165             pf = ParquetFile(paths, open_with=fs.open, **kwargs.get("file", {}))
    166         else:
    167             # Use _common_metadata file if it is available.

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastparquet/api.py in __init__(self, fn, verify, open_with, root, sep, fs)
     91         if isinstance(fn, (tuple, list)):
     92             basepath, fmd = metadata_from_many(fn, verify_schema=verify,
---> 93                                                open_with=open_with, root=root)
     94             if basepath:
     95                 self.fn = join_path(basepath, '_metadata')  # effective file

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastparquet/util.py in metadata_from_many(file_list, verify_schema, open_with, root, fs)
    145 
    146         if verify_schema or fs is None or len(file_list) < 3:
--> 147             pfs = [api.ParquetFile(fn, open_with=open_with) for fn in file_list]
    148         else:
    149             # activate new code path here

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastparquet/util.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    145 
    146         if verify_schema or fs is None or len(file_list) < 3:
--> 147             pfs = [api.ParquetFile(fn, open_with=open_with) for fn in file_list]
    148         else:
    149             # activate new code path here

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastparquet/api.py in __init__(self, fn, verify, open_with, root, sep, fs)
    119                 self.fn = join_path(fn)
    120                 with open_with(fn, 'rb') as f:
--> 121                     self._parse_header(f, verify)
    122             elif "*" in fn or fs.isdir(fn):
    123                 fn2 = join_path(fn, '_metadata')

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastparquet/api.py in _parse_header(self, f, verify)
    161                 if verify:
    162                     assert f.read(4) == b'PAR1'
--> 163                 f.seek(-8, 2)
    164                 head_size = struct.unpack('<i', f.read(4))[0]
    165                 if verify:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

When I run df = dd.read_parquet('/home/vusal.babashov/dataset/cal.parquet', engine='pyarrow'), I get the following error

---

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9b03dc4d018b> in <module>
      1 import dask.dataframe as dd
----> 2 df = dd.read_parquet('/home/vusal.babashov/dataset/cal.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
      3 df

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py in read_parquet(path, columns, filters, categories, index, storage_options, engine, gather_statistics, split_row_groups, read_from_paths, chunksize, aggregate_files, **kwargs)
    290 
    291     if isinstance(engine, str):
--> 292         engine = get_engine(engine)
    293 
    294     if hasattr(path, "name"):

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py in get_engine(engine)
    917 
    918         if pa_version < parse_version("0.13.1"):
--> 919             raise RuntimeError("PyArrow version >= 0.13.1 required")
    920 
    921         if engine == "pyarrow-dataset" and pa_version.major >= 1:

RuntimeError: PyArrow version >= 0.13.1 required
```

I'm using Spark 2.4 and Python 3.7 on the server. The PyArrow version I have is 0.11.1. Upgrading to other versions cause inconsistent environment. According to Dask documentation, default engine is auto which selects fastparquet (I have it installed). When I run df = dd.read_parquet('/home/vusal.babashov/dataset/cal', engine='auto'), I get the same OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

---

```
--
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-361b3123f3d5> in <module>
      1 import dask.dataframe as dd
----> 2 df = dd.read_parquet('/home/vusal.babashov/dataset/cal', engine='auto')
      3 df

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py in read_parquet(path, columns, filters, categories, index, storage_options, engine, gather_statistics, split_row_groups, read_from_paths, chunksize, aggregate_files, **kwargs)
    325         chunksize=chunksize,
    326         aggregate_files=aggregate_files,
--> 327         **kwargs,
    328     )
    329 

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/fastparquet.py in read_metadata(cls, fs, paths, categories, index, gather_statistics, filters, split_row_groups, chunksize, aggregate_files, **kwargs)
    732         # correspond to a row group (populated below).
    733         parts, pf, gather_statistics, base_path = _determine_pf_parts(
--> 734             fs, paths, gather_statistics, **kwargs
    735         )
    736 

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/fastparquet.py in _determine_pf_parts(fs, paths, gather_statistics, **kwargs)
    163         elif gather_statistics is not False:
    164             # Scan every file
--> 165             pf = ParquetFile(paths, open_with=fs.open, **kwargs.get("file", {}))
    166         else:
    167             # Use _common_metadata file if it is available.

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastparquet/api.py in __init__(self, fn, verify, open_with, root, sep, fs)
     91         if isinstance(fn, (tuple, list)):
     92             basepath, fmd = metadata_from_many(fn, verify_schema=verify,
---> 93                                                open_with=open_with, root=root)
     94             if basepath:
     95                 self.fn = join_path(basepath, '_metadata')  # effective file

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastparquet/util.py in metadata_from_many(file_list, verify_schema, open_with, root, fs)
    145 
    146         if verify_schema or fs is None or len(file_list) < 3:
--> 147             pfs = [api.ParquetFile(fn, open_with=open_with) for fn in file_list]
    148         else:
    149             # activate new code path here

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastparquet/util.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    145 
    146         if verify_schema or fs is None or len(file_list) < 3:
--> 147             pfs = [api.ParquetFile(fn, open_with=open_with) for fn in file_list]
    148         else:
    149             # activate new code path here

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastparquet/api.py in __init__(self, fn, verify, open_with, root, sep, fs)
    119                 self.fn = join_path(fn)
    120                 with open_with(fn, 'rb') as f:
--> 121                     self._parse_header(f, verify)
    122             elif "*" in fn or fs.isdir(fn):
    123                 fn2 = join_path(fn, '_metadata')

~/anaconda3/envs/notebookEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastparquet/api.py in _parse_header(self, f, verify)
    161                 if verify:
    162                     assert f.read(4) == b'PAR1'
--> 163                 f.seek(-8, 2)
    164                 head_size = struct.unpack('<i', f.read(4))[0]
    165                 if verify:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

[Parquet Files Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M35t.jpg)

Comment: Why are you using hdfs commands? If you're running a Spark driver in a Jupyter notebook, you can use Spark to write to local disk using `file://` prefix. Also, Linux has no `/user` directory, only HDFS does. Did you mean to use `/home`?

Comment: Yes, that should be /home. I tried file:// but I get the same error. I'm running this on a remote server. I'm just copying the file from HDFS to EdgeNode.

Comment: Like I said, `calendar.write.parquet("file:///home/vusal.babashov/dataset/cal", mode="overwrite")` should work, too. Don't need hdfs commands

Comment: Sorry, I had to make a few changes on my end. The error is actually OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument.

Comment: Well, error is self descriptive. I'm not sure what inconsistent environment issues you're referring to

Answer (score 0):

The invalid argument means that the code is trying to `seek()` to a location in a file that doesn't exist. When reading the metadata footer of a parquet file, the last 8 bytes contain the size of the footer, which is why you seek the `(-8, 2)` (8 bytes before the end of a file).

Very likely the situation is this: spark has written some extra files into the directory that are not data files, such as the weird zero-length "_SUCCESS" file and any checksums; but has *not* written a `_metadata` file to tell dask which files are to be regarded as data.

This issue of filtering for real files I very probably fixed in latest dask and fastparquet (and probably arrow). If you cannot update, then you will need to remove the files that are causing the confusion.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I've attached the snapshot of the parquet files here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M35t.jpg. Does it seem okay to you? Also, I'm using Spark 2.4.0 and Python 3.7 on the server. Are Dask engines ,i.e., fastparquet or pyarrow version compatible?

Comment: Package versions are as follows: dask : 2021.7.2 , fastparquet: 0.7.0,  pyarrow : 0.11.1

Comment: dask dropped 3.7 sometime recently, but fastparquet still supports it.

Comment: Just FYI, I copied the parquet folder to my local PC, I was able to read it into dask using pyarrow but not fastparquet in Python 3.9.7 (conda base).

Comment: do you know if this is still the case for fastparquet 0.8.1?

Comment: Yes. I tried it on version 0.8.1. I get the same error message I posted.

Comment: only via dask, or directly too? (sorry for all the question)